# SharePoint Workflow - Hitting save downloads document

Tags: designer-workflow, 2016

I have a 2010 workflow on a 2016 enterprise environment. In my workflow, I have an email generated that notifies the end-user of a new document. In that email, there's a link to the doc. In Explorer, when the end-user saves metadata on the editform.aspx, it prompts a download of the document rather than just a save. This does not happen in Chrome. How can I prompt it to just save, or save and close rather than prompt a download of the doc? It's confusing for our end-users.

Thanks!